# Drag and Drop on Disabled ImageButton

Tags: android, button, colors, disable

When I drag and drop something onto an image button, I want it to change colour.
This works fine when the button is enabled using this code:

```
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_DROP -> {
   it.background.mutate().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.entered_zone), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
   return@OnDragListener true
}
```

However, if I do:
`endorsedBtn.isEnabled = false`

Then the button will not change colour.
Why is this and is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop):

> Note that this step only occurs if the user drops the drag shadow within the bounding box of **a View whose listener is registered to receive drag events**. If the user releases the drag shadow in any other situation, no ACTION_DROP drag event is sent.

Disabling your image button also disables the listeners for it.

You can create a custom button and decide on your own inner disabling function.

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated(boolean)).

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to stop it from reacting to a click event. I tried btn.isClickable = false, but it still reacts to the click. Do you know of a way to prevent it reacting to a click without disabling it?

Comment: @le0p4rd- if you want to not react to a click and not disabling it, I would suggest adding a flag (or some other logic) and then using it in your click handler.